# populating many form rows with model instances in django not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to build a post and comment system with django. I want whenever an individual post is clicked to be commented on, the post be already populated and also, the request.user be already populated, so that the commenter wont have to select which post he's commenting on or selecting who the commenter is. I actually achieved this when a user wants to make a post, his name will populate the author filed.

views.py:

```py
@login_required(login_url="login")
def make_tweet_view(request):
    author = request.user
    form = make_tweet_form(initial={"author": author})
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = make_tweet_form(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context= {'forms': form}
    return render(request, "hometweet/make-tweet.html", context)
```

But somehow trying this doesnt work for my comment view

mycomment view:

```py
def comment_view(request, id):
    posts = Post.objects.get(id = id)
    user = request.user
    forms= comment_form(initial={"user": user, "posts":posts})
    if request.method == "POST":
        forms= comment_form(request.POST or None)
        if forms.is_valid():
            forms.save()
    context = {"forms": forms}
    return render(request, "hometweet/comment.html", context)
```

my models and their relationships:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    pics = models.ImageField(null= True, blank= True, upload_to= 'images/')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name= "post_author")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.content}"
    

class Coment(models.Model):
    comment_post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name= "post_comments")
    comment_author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name= "comment_author")
    comments = models.TextField()
    comment_pics = models.ImageField(null= True, blank= True, upload_to= 'images/')
    comment_date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

the comment template file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>comment</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{forms.as_p}}
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the comment form class is something like this:

```
# forms.py

from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Comment

class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = "__all__"
        # this is equivalent to writing all model fields
        # fields = ["comment_post", "comment_author", "comments", "comment_pics", "comment_date_created"]
```

If you want to populate some of the fields then you use a dictionary where the key is the field's name and the value is what you want to populate the form field with:

```
# views.py

from .forms import CommentForm

# ...

def comment_view(request, id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    user = request.user
    form = CommentForm(initial={"comment_post": post, "comment_author": user})
    # ...
```